How to convert one time zone to another timezone using Day.js
I'm receiving data in "America/New_York" timeZone. 
I want to convert that data into "Asia/Calcutta" from "America/New_York".
How to do that using Day.js ?

it's in the documentation here:  https://day.js.org/docs/en/timezone/converting-to-zone#docsNav

import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc';
import timezone from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone';

// Extend dayjs with the plugins
dayjs.extend(utc);
dayjs.extend(timezone);

// Example date string in "America/New_York" timezone
const dateInNewYork = '2024-08-14T12:00:00'; // Example date and time

// Convert the date to "Asia/Calcutta" timezone
const dateInCalcutta = dayjs.tz(dateInNewYork, 'America/New_York').tz('Asia/Calcutta');

// Format or display the date in "Asia/Calcutta" timezone
console.log(dateInCalcutta.format()); // Outputs the date in "Asia/Calcutta" timezone


OK I understand my mistake. We need to convert input date-time format as: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss (dayjs(timezone1_time).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')` ) and then apply the conversion.
Thank you @AdesojiAlu for quick solution ..
